# Нужна ли запятая после "но вот"?

Tags: пунктуация, частица

*Но вот что-то проносится...* Нужна ли запятая после "но вот"?

Answer (score 3):

Но вот что-то проносится... Нет запятой после указательной частицы ВОТ.

ВОТ, частица. 1. Указывает на кого-, что-л., находящееся или происходящее перед глазами, в непосредственной близости или при рассказывании как бы перед глазами.

Answer (score 0):

> *Но вот что-то проносится...*
>
> Нужна ли запятая после "но вот"?

Запятая не нужна. Но при наличии паузы после "но вот" может быть поставлено интонационное тире.

См. [**примеры в Нацкорпусе**](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%EE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%E2%EE%F2&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=bdash&m2=).